# Why is pandas.DataFrame().groupby().apply(func) called more often than there are groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I've written a test script to understand `pandas.DataFrame().groupby().apply()`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([("a",1),("b",2),("b",1)], columns=["idx", "col1"])

def my_apply(group):
    print(group)
    return group

df.groupby("idx").apply(my_apply)
```

As a result the dataframe for the group `"a"` is printed twice. It seems always the first one is called twice, but the result from the first call is thrown away.

Why does `my_apply` seem to be called twice for the first group?

Comment: With one `a` and two `b`s it's still the first group that gets printed twice.

Comment: Yes, I'll improve my example.